# PHP outputting in XML

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to output the results of a PHP script in XML but not with great results.

This is the one line XML file I get (with no error message)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and this is what I would like to see

```
<data>
    <thread>
        <id>my data here</id>
        <author>
            <name>my data here/name>
            <url>my data here</url>
            <id>my data here</id>
        </author>
        <title>my data here</title>
        <reactions>my data here</reactions>
        <dislikes>my data here</dislikes>
        <userScore>my data here</userScore>
        <createdAt>my data here</createdAt>
        <slug>my data here</slug>
        <postNumber>my data here</postNumber>
        <link>my data here</link>
        <likes>my data here</likes>
        <message>my data here</message>
        <category>my data here</category>
        <score>my data here</score>
        <categoryLink>my data here</categoryLink>
    </thread>        
</data>
```

This is my code:

```
//Create XML

$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'UTF-8');

$root = $xml->createElement("data");
$xml->appendChild($root);

$thread = $xml->createElement("thread");


$threadID = $xml->createElement("id");
$threadID->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->id));
$thread->appendChild($threadID);

$author = $xml->createElement("author");                          
$thread->appendChild($author);

 $authorName = $xml->createElement("name");
 $authorName->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($parsed_authorName));
 $author->appendChild($authorName);

 $authorUrl = $xml->createElement("url");
 $authorUrl->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($parsed_authorUrl));
 $author->appendChild($authorUrl);

 $authorID = $xml->createElement("id");
 $authorID->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->author));
 $author->appendChild($authorID);

$threadTitle = $xml->createElement("title");
$threadTitle->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->title));
$thread->appendChild($threadTitle);

$threadReactions = $xml->createElement("reactions");
$threadReactions->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->reactions));
$thread->appendChild($threadReactions);

$threadDislikes = $xml->createElement("dislikes");
$threadDislikes->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->dislikes));
$thread->appendChild($threadDislikes);

$threadUserScore = $xml->createElement("userScore");
$threadUserScore->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->userScore));
$thread->appendChild($threadUserScore);

$threadCreatedAt = $xml->createElement("createdAt");
$threadCreatedAt->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->createdAt));
$thread->appendChild($threadCreatedAt);

$threadSlug = $xml->createElement("slug");
$threadSlug->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->slug));
$thread->appendChild($threadSlug);

$threadPostNumber = $xml->createElement("postNumber");
$threadPostNumber->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->posts));
$thread->appendChild($threadPostNumber);

$threadLink = $xml->createElement("link");
$threadLink->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->link));
$thread->appendChild($threadLink);

$threadLikes = $xml->createElement("likes");
$threadLikes->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->likes));
$thread->appendChild($threadLikes);

$threadMessage = $xml->createElement("likes");
$threadMessage->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($parsed_threadMessage));
$thread->appendChild($threadMessage);

$threadCategory = $xml->createElement("category");
$threadCategory->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($details->category));
$thread->appendChild($threadCategory);

$threadScore = $xml->createElement("likes");
$threadScore->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($parsed_threadScore));
$thread->appendChild($threadScore);

$threadCategoryLink = $xml->createElement("likes");
$threadCategoryLink->appendChild($xml->createTextNode($parsed_threadCategoryLink));
$thread->appendChild($threadCategoryLink);

$thread->appendChild($root);

$xml->formatOutput = true;

echo "<xmp>". $xml->saveXML() ."</xmp>";

$xml->save("test1.xml") or die("Error");
```

Could be the order in which I append the XML elements is wrong?

Comment: Near to the end, you write `$thread->appendChild($root);`, I think this is `$root->appendChild($thread);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near to the end, you write

```
$thread->appendChild($root);
```

I think this is

```
$root->appendChild($thread);
```

Because you want to add your THREAD node to the ROOT node